# Python3.5 Import Error on my project

Tags: python

My project directory:

```
project
├── folder1
├── folder2
└── src
    |
    ├──__init__.py
    |
    ├── mod1
    |    ├──__init__.py
    |    ├──file_a.py
    |    └──file_b.py
    |
    └── mod2
         ├──__init__.py
         └──file_c.py
```

---

The first question is:

In my **linux server** (Ubuntu 14.04 with python3.5)

file_a.py:

```
import file_b
# that's work
....
```

file_b.py:

```
from src.mod2 import file_c
# get No module named 'src'
# Or:
from ..mod2 import file_c
# get Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Note that I got these error by run

```
python3 file_a.py
```

---

The second question is:

In my **macOS with Pycharm CE**, I must have

file_a.py:

```
from src.mod1 import file_b
...
```

If I use `import file_b` directly, I'll get `ImportError`

I don't know what's wrong with my project.

Hoping for your help, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you import the same way as file_b? `from src.mod1 import file_a`

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) but I don't need to use file_a in my file_b, my purpose is to use file_c in file_b

Comment: Maybe you should add the path for file_c?
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/' + '../mod2'))
 
from src.mod2 import file_c

or something like that?

Comment: @ymmx Thanks! It works! But I still don't know what I did wrong in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
from src.mod2.file_c import name_of_your_module_in_file_c
```